# VSC not giving auto complete options for javascript when manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, dom, autocomplete

I am a beginner at using javascript. For that reason, I really need to see all the options and the correct names when coding. I will provide a small sample of the code to show the problem.

```js
function delItem (e){
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    console.log("1");
  }
}
```

The problem is when I type `e.` and nothing close to the 'target' keyword shows. Same with 'classList' and 'contains'.

I have looked at other solutions and I have both the ESlint and JavaScript (ES6) code snippets. I have also checked that I have javascript autocomplete turned on in the settings.

Comment: VSC does not know the type of the variable `e`, so no suggestions, use a JSDOC string to set the type of the parameter